# Error output of the tf-hub layers embedding with Conv or Rnn

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-hub

Here is the code, the idea is I want to build a multi lang sentiment classifier, but here the issue is:
(tensorflow 2.0.1), (tf-hub 0.7.0)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub


ml_module = hub.load('https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual/3')
module = hub.KerasLayer(ml_module , dtype=tf.string, trainable=False, name='bert_embedding')

input_text = tf.keras.Input((), dtype=tf.string, name='input_text')
embedding = module(input_text)
conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(32, 2, padding='valid', activation='relu', strides=1)(embedding)
dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation="relu")(conv1)
layer1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(9, name='sentiment')(dense1)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=input_text, outputs=layer1)


ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv1d_3 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 512]
```

Maybe I can try with a keras lambda function to resize the output of the embedding but I didn't find a way to make it works

Do you guys have any ideas ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You may add a `Reshape` layer to change the shape from `[ None , 512 ]` to `[ None , 512 , 1 ]`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub


ml_module = hub.load('https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual/3')
module = hub.KerasLayer(ml_module , dtype=tf.string, trainable=False, name='bert_embedding')
input_text = tf.keras.Input((), dtype=tf.string, name='input_text')
embedding = module(input_text)

reshape = tf.keras.layers.Reshape( target_shape=( None , 512 , 1 ) )( embedding )

conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(32, 2, padding='valid', activation='relu', strides=1)(reshape)
dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation="relu")(conv1)
layer1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(9, name='sentiment')(dense1)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=input_text, outputs=layer1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Oh thank you Shubham it works =D

This is the code to make it works

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub


ml_module = hub.load('https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual/3')
module = hub.KerasLayer(ml_module , dtype=tf.string, trainable=False, name='bert_embedding')
input_text = tf.keras.Input((), dtype=tf.string, name='input_text')
embedding = module(input_text)

reshape = tf.keras.layers.Reshape(target_shape=(512, 1))(embedding)
conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters, kernel, padding='valid', activation='relu', strides=1)(reshape)
gpool1 = tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D()(conv1)
dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(dims, activation="relu")(gpool1)
dropout1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(dense1)
layer1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_classes, name='sentiment')(dropout1)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=input_text, outputs=layer1)
```